# How to serve https links with Laravel 5 url() blade helper

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am looking for a way to server secure links via `url()` helper in blade files.

Like you have `assets` and `assets_secure`, is there any option or a way to serve only https through this helper?

It's in a million places across my app and it would really be great to find a way to serve those links like that, but still have them with https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In laravel 5.3 has `secure_url()`

> The `secure_url` function generates a fully qualified HTTPS URL to the
>   given path:
>
> `echo secure_url('user/profile');`
>
> `echo secure_url('user/profile', [1]);`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-secure-url